# Batch - copy of a file for backup

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I am trying to make a copy of a file in a folder having the name of today. If the folder exists it just makes the copy inside, if not it will create the folder and copy it there. Here is what I am doing

```
setlocal

Y:
set dateT=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%
set "pathFiles=Y:\Myfolder\"
set pathBackup = %pathFiles%%dateT%

pause
if not exist %pathBackup% (
    mkdir %pathBackup%
)

cd %pathBackup%
robocopy C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file.mdb %pathBackup%
```

It is not really working, do you see any errors ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry the question was where is the problem... Thanks for helping

Comment: You are lucky someone took the time to go through your script. In future, please try to be more specific than "It is not really working". You'll get help quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question is formulated, this is what can be seen

Problems with variables

```
                v--- Space included in value
set pathBackup = %pathFiles%%dateT%
              ^----- Space included in variable name

set "pathBackup=%pathFiles%%dateT%"
```

Maybe problems with spaces in paths. Better use quotes

```
if not exist "%pathBackup%\" (
    mkdir "%pathBackup%"
)
```

Wrong `robocopy` usage. You are using the `copy` or `xcopy` syntax. In `robocopy` you use `sourceFolder targetFolder fileMask` as arguments.

```
robocopy "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop" "%pathBackup%" file.mdb
xcopy "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file.mdb" "%pathBackup%"
copy "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file.mdb" "%pathBackup%"
```